# Is it possible to have the CombinedManipulator use left click instead of right in Helix Toolkit WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, input, helix-3d-toolkit

I'm using the CombinedManipulator and everything is working great, but I'd like to change it to use left click instead of right. I've looked through all the docs and I haven't found anything that would help me. I did see this but I couldn't seem to implement it correctly.

Heres my HelixViewport xaml:

```
<helix:HelixViewport3D x:Name="viewPort3d" ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="true"
                           Margin="0,0,290.6,173.6" Background="Black" MouseLeftButtonUp="Viewport3D_MouseMove" 
                           SnapMouseDownPoint="False" Height="638" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                           ShowCameraInfo="True" MinimumFieldOfView="45" >
        <helix:DefaultLights/>
        <helix:CombinedManipulator x:Name="rTManipulator" CanRotateX="True" CanRotateY="True" CanRotateZ="True" />
</helix:HelixViewport3D>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`CombinedManipulator`](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/blob/develop/Source/HelixToolkit.Wpf.Shared/Visual3Ds/Manipulators/CombinedManipulator.cs) internally uses `RotateManipulator` and `TranslateManipulator` which in turn react to `OnMouseDown` and `OnMouseMove` events (see source code [here](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/blob/46dcdba7bb6337cbe491b5b38deff51ebf073932/Source/HelixToolkit.Wpf.Shared/Visual3Ds/Manipulators/TranslateManipulator.cs#L116)). I suggest you fork the project and edit the components to match your needs, ie filter on left/right click as you see fit. You can also submit a PR to the project which is still acively maintained.